# Using custom services or liferay services in liferay themes (velocity templates)?

Tags: service, liferay, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

How to use custom services method in liferay themes in velocity files like `init_custom.vm`, `portal_normal.vm` etc.

I see liferay provides a lot of variables of helper utility classes like `$portalUtil` for [`PortalUtil`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil.java), `$getterUtil` for [`GetterUtil`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/GetterUtil.java) and so on, inside the [`init.vm`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/themes/_unstyled/templates/init.vm) file.

So is it possible to get instance of my custom services like an instance of `com.my.custom.service.MyCustomLocalServiceImpl` or services of liferay from `UserLocalServiceImpl`?

Here is some psuedo code, to give an idea of what I need:

```
// this code calls method from MyCustomLocalServiceImpl class to fetch items
#set ($listOfItems = $myCustomLocalServiceUtil.getAllItems())

// this code calls method from UserLocalServiceImpl class to fetch users
#set ($listOfUsers = $userLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0, 99))
```

Environment: Liferay 6.1 CE GA1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.

1. The following code shows how to get the services:

   ```
   // Fetching instance of my custom services
   #set ($myCustomLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService('myCustomServices-portlet', 'com.my.custom.service.MyCustomLocalService'))

   // Fetching instance of UserLocalServiceImpl
   #set ($userLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService'))
   ```
2. Then simply call the service methods:

   ```
   #set ($listOfItems = $myCustomLocalService.getAllItems())

   #set ($listOfUsers = $userLocalService.getUsers(0, 99))
   ```

<sub>For Liferay 6.1 CE GA1: I found this class [`VelocityVariablesImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.java#L104) (see methods like [`insertHelperUtilities`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.java#L106), [`insertVariables`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/velocity/VelocityVariablesImpl.java#L586)) which actually makes all the variables and helper utilities available to the velocity templates.</sub>

Comment: My ftl is notworking after 

${serviceLocator.findService('com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService')}

Comment: can u elaborate what do u mean by not working? any errors or exceptions? You may ask another question with full ftl and the version you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend velocity context used in theme with custom variables and services using following hook plugin. Let's say you need to use your custom local service.

1. create a hook plugin with following liferay-hook.xml definition

   ```
   <hook>
       <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
   </hook>
   ```
2. create **portal.properties** in `main/resources` (when you use maven) or in `docroot/WEB-INF/src` (when you use plugins sdk), place following configuration there

   ```
   servlet.service.events.pre=com.my.custom.action.MyCustomPreAction
   ```
3. create `com.my.custom.action.MyCustomPreAction` class in your hook that will extend `com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action`
4. implement `run` method

   ```
   @Override
   public void run(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ActionException {

       Map<String, Object> vmVariables = (Map<String, Object>) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.VM_VARIABLES);
       if (vmVariables == null) {
         vmVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
       }
       vmVariables.put("myCustomServiceUtil", com.my.custom.service.MyCustomLocalServiceUtil.class);
       request.setAttribute(WebKeys.VM_VARIABLES, map);
   }
   ```
5. after your hook is deployed you can use your custom service in velocity template of your theme

   ```
   // this code calls method from MyCustomLocalServiceImpl class to fetch items
   #set ($listOfItems = $myCustomServiceUtil.getAllItems())
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That is a nice way too.